# SCP copy remote to local returns "Read-only file system" error on remote folder

Tags: scp, readonly

I used the following command:

```
scp -r root@IP:/home/user/remotefolder /localfolder
```

After entering my passphrase (I'm using SSH key), I get the following error:

```
/remotefolder: Read-only file system
```

Not sure why I get this error. When I log in as root, I can copy this folder to another location within the server, but the command above doesn't work. Since I'm copying from remote to local, why would a read-only folder/file affect a copy?

Comment: Have you double-checked that `/localfolder` is not on a read-only mount? I think the error message is supposed to be understood as "while copying `/remotefolder`, the following error occurred: …"

Comment: /localfolder is my mac machine. I previously had an error where i used /Download and it stated that it was read-only. Changing localfolder to / fixed it (I assume) and the error was subsequently /remotefolder.

Comment: @SottoVoce it worked, thank you so much!

Comment: what is trhe root filesystem on you mac?

Comment: Please update your question with the _exact_ (unmodified) command and error message.

Answer (score 1):

In your last argument to the `scp` command, try `~/localfolder` instead of `/localfolder`. You don't have permission to create a folder under your Mac's root folder (`/`), but you do have permission to create it under your home folder (`~/`).

Comment: Note that the error mentions `/remotefolder`, not `/localfolder`. I'm hoping that's a typo, but that's what the question currently says.

Comment: @Kusalananda the comments on the question, which added useful information, used `/localfolder` as the local folder name.  I'm sure the actual command spacified the same folder name for both remote and local, and the OP assumed the error was about the remote computer permissions instead of local computer permissions.  My answer was originally a comment and the OP commented that my advice worked.

Comment: Yes it was the remotefolder. Initially when I used /User/localfolder, it stated that read only error was at the local folder. When I changed it, the error was on the remote folder. “~” fixed it

Comment: @Limerick This makes no sense.

Comment: @Kusalananda I believe Limerick's comment is saying the same thing as my comment.